# Find the weights or kernel used by gaussian_filter of scipy.ndimage

Tags: python, scipy, gaussian, ndimage

I am having an image consisting of {0,1,2} values and I am trying to run gaussian_filter from scipy.ndimage over it. Though it was very easy to use but I haven't understood the things properly yet.

Few things that I understood are :

- sigma is the standard deviation used for assigning weights in the kernel
- Gaussian filter on a 2D image is implemented in the form of 1D gaussian filters
- the size of the kernel depends upon sigma as well as truncate value [[Gaussian filter in scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216382/gaussian-filter-in-scipy])

I want to know the weights being used in the gaussian filter.
Is there some way to get the kernel used from the gaussian_filter call itself or some formula by which I can have that kernel.

I want this just for better understanding of weightage I am giving to different neighboring pixels in my image.

for example what will be kernel for

> ndimage.gaussian_filter(image,sigma=0.2)
>
> ndimage.gaussian_filter(image,sigma=0.2,truncate=2)