# Why scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter doesn't have a kernel size?

Tags: python, image, scipy

Why the function `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` let choose a value of `sigma` but no the size of the kernel?
Theoretically, the kernel size must increase with increasing σ to maintain the Gaussian nature of the filter.
Does Scipy do this automatically? How?

Comment: I wrote some notes about it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216382/gaussian-filter-in-scipy/25217058#25217058

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does that automatically based on the `sigma` and `truncate` parameters.

Indeed, the function `gaussian_filter` is implemented by applying multiples 1D gaussian filters (you can see that [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/ae34ce4/scipy/ndimage/filters.py#L219-L302)). This function uses `gaussian_filter1d` which generate itself the kernel using `_gaussian_kernel1d` with a radius of `int(truncate * sigma + 0.5)`.