# how do I implement Gaussian filter with kernel [3,3] in python?

Tags: python

I need to implement Gaussian filter 2d with kernel size [3,3] in python, but I do not know how can I do this? I use this method in Matlab:

```
G = fspecial('gaussian',[3 3],0.5);
Ig = imfilter(watermarkImage,G,'same');
```

but in python, we have some function like this

```
blurred_img = gaussian_filter(img, Q, mode='reflect')
```

that `Q` is the std and I do not know how can I produce a blurred image with kernel [3,3]. could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25217058/14872512) on how to calculate sigma from the width you want (3 here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` has the argument `truncate`, which sets the filter size (truncation) in `sigma`. Your sigma here is 0.5, and assuming 3 x 3 is symmetrical around the centre, that would mean it truncates at 3/2 = 1.5 = 3 sigma. So you could use `gaussian_filter(img, 0.5, order=0, truncate=3.0)` and see if you get the same result as your matlab code.

Note that the documentation for `fspecial`, for the case of a Gaussian filter, mentions it is not recommended to use this function, but to use `imgaussfilt` or `imgaussfilt3` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If OpenCV is option then it has function for this, namely [cv2.GaussianBlur](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering) it does accept width and height of the kernel (both should be odd and positive) and standard deviation, so using kernel size [3,3] and deviation 0.5, would be as follow:

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3),0.5)
```

where `img` is array representing image, possibly created by using `cv2.imread` function.